# Adding a property to array items results in "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query"

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a property into nested arrays

```
var names = [...]; // long list of names, omitted for the sake of brevity

var isNotCriteria = {
    "Persons.Name": {
        $nin: names
    }
}

var isNotUpdateStatement = {
    $set: {
        "Persons.$.IsVerified" : false
    }
}

db["teams"].updateMany(isNotCriteria, isNotUpdateStatement);
```

An example of a `teams` document structure:

```
{
   "_id": "32bace05-2742-4bee-9d56-6e4f168e742b",
   "Name" : "TeamA",
   "Persons" : [{
       "_id" : "5794aa39-8ebf-421d-a28b-ab34d1ccfb2h",
       "Name" : "Person 1"
   }, {
       "_id" : "42602118-cc4a-4121-b869-365d6f73e1d0",
       "Name" : "Person 2"
   }]
}
```

However, execution results in exception:

> The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
>   Unexpanded update: Persons.$.IsVerified

I can't understand the reason of failure, because if I switch criteria query from `$nin` to `$in` it works.
If I run `find` with the this criteria I do see results:

```
db["teams"].find(isNotCriteria);
```

Any idea how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue turns out to be `teams` documents that do not have `Persons` array (or array is empty).
I changed the criteria query to

```
var isNotCriteria = {
    $and: [
         {
             "Persons": {
                 $exists: true,
                 $not: {$size : 0} 
             },
             "Persons.Name" : {
                  $nin: names
             }
         }
     ]
 }
```

And now it works as expected.